# loading rLingo package for R

Tags: r, lingo

Working with R (ver 3.4.1) and Lingo (ver 16), attempting to install rlingo package using the provided direction within Lingo documentation via command prompt.

I get the following error message:

```
******************
Checking for R...
Checking for Rtools...
Checking for LINGO16...
Checking source package rLingo_16.0.tar.gz...
Ok.. Installing...
* installing to library 'C:/Users/mike kennedy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4'
* installing *source* package 'rLingo' ...

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:\LINGO64_16\/Programming Samples"    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rLingo.c -o rLingo.o

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rLingo.dll tmp.def rLingo.o -LC:\LINGO64_16\/ -lLingd64_16 -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lR

installing to C:/Users/mike kennedy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rLingo/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rLingo' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/mike kennedy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rLingo/libs/x64/rLingo.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rLingo'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rLingo'
Finished
************************
```

I checked the Lingo directory and the 'install-rlingo' batch file is there. Any help in  correcting the installation issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WE found the solution to this issue. Updated our LINGO application to ver 17. The rlingo package loads properly now.